# When I use Entry with .NET MAUI, the underscore appears. How do I remove it?

Tags: android, .net, xamarin, maui

`<Entry Placeholder="Username" />`

Underscore appears when using entry. What I want is an entry without underlines.

[image]
The photo I took is the structure I don't want

[image]

[image]

How do I set up this build? Is there a simple way?

Comment: Like this https://enisn-projects.io/docs/en/uranium/latest/themes/material/components/TextField

Comment: Keyword you are looking for is "material design" or "material ui". This UI pattern is pretty common in various technologies. @Bas H answer is pretty valid. That library is material ui for dotnet maui. If you want to have more control over your styles, you need to dive into xaml control styling. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/styles/xaml?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: now there is an underscore on that too. I think this problem came with a new update.

Comment: Is it very difficult to write a stable and well-running system like textfield in Flutter with .net maui?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That's an Android specific situation. If you want to change it, you can customize the appearance of the Entry control. A general documentation for customization of controls can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0 However, it's also important to understand that Flutter and MAUI are fundamentally different. Flutter **draws** all controls using Skia. MAUI uses platform native controls for most UI components, which is why certain controls look different on each platform.

Comment: So, do you think Maui or Flutter is better and more performant? @ewerspej

Comment: This is not a forum for opinions on which technology is better, so I won't give you a specific answer on that and recommend reading the guidelines instead: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Generally, it depends on what you want to do and which technology you're more comfortable with. Both have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you can use the handler to make the entry hide the underscore by set the android's platform view's background as null. Such as:

In the page.xaml:

```
<Entry x:Name="entry" Placeholder="This is an entry" />
```

In the page.cs:

```
      protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if ANDROID
            var edittext = entry.Handler.PlatformView as Android.Widget.EditText;
            edittext.Background = null;
#endif
      }
```

If you want to all the entry on the android hide the underscore, you can use the custom handler for the android.

Add the handler class in the /YourProject/Platforms/Android:

```
namespace MauiAppTest.Platforms.Android
{
      public class MyEntryHandler : Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler
      {
            protected override void ConnectHandler(AppCompatEditText platformView)
            {
                  platformView.Background = null;
                  base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
            }
      }
}
```

And use the handler in the mauiprogram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                  {
#if ANDROID
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Entry), typeof(MauiAppTest.Platforms.Android.MyEntryHandler));
#endif
                  });
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: I have had this forever now in my library https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls and so much more !!

Answer (score 0):

I have a packed library that removes all the visual effects of input controls:
https://github.com/enisn/Xamarin.Forms.Plainer

You can use the package or you can import only required handlers into your project.